# Contentful How to resolve child reference links?

Tags: javascript, contentful, contentful-management

I am querying contenful with following call:

```
space.getEntries({ content_type: contentTypeId, order: '-sys.createdAt', skip: 0}).catch(function(gerror) {
   return gerror;
}).then(function(entries) {
   console.log(entries);
});
```

But i am getting sys object in the response instead of full object which contains asset url etc.

[image]

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the tags you added, it seems like you are using the management API?

The management API does not do automated link resolution. This is a feature of the Delivery API only.